# Сохранить рамку при изменение изображеняе в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

На сцене есть кнопки, у которой Source Image - изображение с разрешением 1:1 (Картинка 1). Но кнопка, добавляемая на сцену имеет разрешение не 1:1. Поэтому изображение растягивается. По сути, изображение представляет из себя рамку прямоугольника со скругленными краями. Но из за того, что изображение растянуто (см. скрин - красная и синяя рамки - это и есть кнопки) сверху и снизу толщина рамки больше, но мне нужно, чтобы толщина по всем сторонам была одна и та же. Я бы мог изначально использовать изображение с нужными пропорциями, но тут есть одно но: в процессе игры размер и пропорции кнопки меняется, поэтому опять будет искажение толщины рамки. Как мне решить эту проблему?

[image: Картинка 1]

[image: Картинка 2]

Comment: Я мало что понял. Причем тут картинка и причем тут контур. Да, в скрипте можно менять и кнопку и картинки и вообще все что угодно. Может некий визуальный ряд добавите в вопрос? Изображения что есть и что надо. Чтоб внести больше ясности в вопрос.

Comment: Не понял абсолютно ничего, перепишите пожалуйста вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Импортируй в Unity свой спрайт.
2. Сделай такие настройки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Открой Sprite Editor. Перетащи зеленые линии так, что бы они обозначали твою рамку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Выбери свою кнопку и в компоненте Image выбери ImageType - Sliced

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5. Готово

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]